# Import all number from string to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Need to find all numbers in string. (54g not number etc.) and import to array. How to import number to array? And how get rid of 87) ect.?

```
    #include "stdio.h"
int main() {
    char *pS;
    int i;
    char str[100];
    short isn = 0;
    gets(str);
    pS = str;
    int a[100]={0};
    i=0;
    while (*pS) {
        if (*pS >= '0' && *pS <= '9') {
            isn = 1;
            printf("%c", *pS);
        } 
        else {
            if (isn) {
                isn = 0;
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        pS++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post sample input and the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on your requirements, but based on the code you've posted it appears you want to treat all adjacent digits as a single value and ignore any non-digits in between.  If that's the case, I would approach this by first converting all non-digits to a common character value (pick any non-digit character), then use `strtok` to tokenize the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str[100];
    char* s;
    int a[100];
    int count;
    int len;
    int i;

    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    /* change all non-digits to spaces */
    len = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (!isdigit(str[i]))
            str[i] = ' ';
    }

    count = 0;

    /* tokenize on spaces and append to array */
    s = strtok(str, " ");
    while (s != NULL) {
        a[count++] = atoi(s);
        s = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    /* output final array */
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!